# process-specific /etc/hosts

Tags: macos, unix, networking, testing, hosts

I'm developing a service that talks to other services. To test these interaction, I have a fake http server. I'm using node.js and test via http requests. The tests are running external to the process, so I cannot (and don't want to) mock the request/response.

So far, I have an environment variable that allows me to switch hosts within the service itself. However, I cannot base the fake request/response on the hostname.

I also run a development version of the service that interacts with the real external services. I could programmatically change /etc/hosts during the test run, as I probably won't be "using" the development service while running tests, but I'd rather keep the purity of the test sandbox.

Ideally, I'd like to have a version of /etc/hosts apply only to the process. This would allow the fake http server to also glean the intended host of the request.

I'm also open to different approaches to achieving the test hostname sandbox.

Comment: I dont understand.. just add the entires to the hosts file pointing to your local machine and then bind your fake server on port `80` or some other port... I dont think youre going to be bale to do it per process unless you fake the entire process of DNS lookup/resolution. As far as determining which host the request was for that should be in the HTTP headers... You just need to parse it and act on it in your fake HTTP server program.

Comment: I'd rather keep the host aliases local to the process, as I also run a development version of the service (using the real external services) on the same machine.

Comment: You are correct that I could have a different test hostname for each service. That should alleviate the question of the intended service destination.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/hosts` is used among other things by `gethostbyname()`, a system call that is actually performing the resolving.

There's no easy way to do it the way you want it.

How about a local DNS server with fake names/addresses?

Comment: The problem with the DNS server is that it is (AFAIK) global to all processes. I also run a development version of the service that interacts with the real external services.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for a lot of implementations but it may not be feasible for you.  You have a UNIX/OSX tag, so:

You have to put your process in what amounts to a chroot jail.  chroot changes the root `/` to be some other location, ex.: `/localroot`.

You can then create your version of hosts under `/localroot/etc/hosts`.  It is seen by the chrooted process as /etc/hosts

There is a lot of information on how to set one up on the web.  And any user account you create is "locked" in there.

I cannot find basic OSX chroot information, this is more advanced, and is meant primarily for sftp users.:

http://www.macresearch.org/restricted-sftp-mac-os-x-leopard